# Pelican CSS Path

Tags: python, css, pelican

Random little pelican problem if anyone can help me.

I am writing a theme which is structures like this.

```
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── js
│   └── img
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── page.html
```

In the index.html file I'm using this to call the static css, img and js files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/base.css"/>
```

For the page.html I then 'extend' the base.html with this line

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
```

When I generate the html in to the output folder all works fine for the index.html but the page.html can't find the static files as it will need a new path. This is the output folder setup.

```
├── theme
|   ├── css
│   ├── js
│   └── img
├── index.html
└── pages
    └── page.html
```

If you see the page.html can't load the css by using the path theme/css/base.css

Is there a way to use a {{ ROUTE }} command when loading static files?

Thanks!

Edit 1
After looking at some other theme's index.html page on Github I see they use the {{ SITEURL }} tag but that doesn't work for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ SITEURL }}theme/css/base.css"/>
```

Edit 2 
I've fixed this by using the following line in the pelicanconf.py file

```
RELATIVE_URLS = True
```

and the following in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ SITEURL }}/theme/css/base.css"/>
```

Comment: can't you add `/` at the beginning - `"/theme/css/base.css"` ?

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid that doesn't work. It just breaks it a bit further as index.html doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when developing locally and was able to resolve it by setting `SITEURL = '.'`.